# Checking for integers in a string - python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer

I have a program that asks the user's name:

```
while True:
try:
    name = str(input("Please enter your name > "))
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a valid name")
    continue
else:
    break
```

I want to prevent the user from entering an integer, but with the code above integers are accepted in a string. How can I prevent the user from entering an integer in the string?

Comment: Are you checking if the string is *just* numbers?

Comment: just text, no numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` when trying to cast to an int if an exception is raised as it is not an int:

```
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your name > ")
    try:
        int(name)
    except ValueError:
        break        
    print("Please enter a valid name")
```

`str.digit` might work also but will fail on negative input.

To check if any character is a digit use any:

```
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your name > ")
    if any(ch.isdigit() for ch in name):
        print("Please enter a valid name")
    else:
        break
```

You could also create a set of accepted characters:

```
from string import ascii_letters
st = set(ascii_letters)
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your name > ")
    if not st.issuperset(name):
        print("Please enter a valid name")
    else:
        break
```

Where you might want to add `-, " "` and any other potential characters.

Comment: Oops, Forgot that you could cheat `try`

Comment: You could also use `str.isalpha`.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, `foo-bar` is a valid name as is `Lord foobar`

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, do not cast `str` as `input` returns an `str`. Note from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

> The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that

After you get the input into `name` you can have a `if` condition.

```
name = str(input("Please enter your name > "))
if (re.search('\d',name)):
     print("Sorry your name contains a number")
```

And don't forget to [`import re`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string method [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to check if the string is just integers.

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
if name.isdigit() == True:
    print ("That's not a name!")
```

Likewise, you can also use the method [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to check if the string is just text. However, if there's a space, it will return False.

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
if name.isalpha() != True:
    print ("That's not a name!")
```

Comment: `if name.isdigit()` will do but `-100` is a digit and `if not name.isalpha()` will also be sufficient

Comment: The only problem with `isalpha()` is that some names contain punctuation characters, like a dash.

Comment: names also contain spaces

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's true.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
if len(set(name) - set('1234567890')) < len(set(name)):
    name = input("Please enter a valid name: ")
```